# Loading tmux sessions from file

Tags: terminal, tmux

I'd like to be able in tmux to load sessions saved in a file including window/pane and shell setups. I have this in ~/.tmux/my_session:

```
new -d -s test1
neww -k -t test1:1 top

new -d -s test2
neww -k -t test2:1 -n '2w1' 
neww -t test2 -n '2w2'
```

Now I source it in tmux and this works fine: I have two detached sessions test1 (with one window) and test2 with 2 windows. But I'd like to actually run also some commands, e.g. replace the last line with:

```
neww -t test2 -n '2w2' 'cd ~/work; ./myscript.zsh ; ls'
```

So that it cds to the directory, runs some setup scrip, does `ls` and **stays** open for further use. According to the manual however windows close automatically after command finishes. There is an option `remain-on-exit` but it's not clear how could I combine it it with `neww` so that it actually works...

Also the manual list a -c flag for `neww` to set starting dir, but my `homebrew` installed `tmux v1.6` doesn't seem to recognize it.

`teamocil` seems to be able to do it so it has to be possible (but `teamocil` doesn't keep the sessions separate which is essential for me).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is send-keys:

```
new -d -s test1
neww -k -t test1:1 -n '1w1'
send-keys -t test1:1 "echo '1w1'" C-m

new -d -s test2
neww -k -t test2:1 -n '2w1'
neww -t test2 -n '2w2'
send-keys -t test2:1 "echo '2w1'" C-m
send-keys -t test2:2 "echo '2w2'" C-m

display-message "Sessions loaded!"
```

Comment: Please, explain it in details

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure tmuxinator can keep things separate.

Comment: so can teamocil, and it has a great `.yml` config format